# Tried everything, cannot configure SAMBA on my Ubuntu systems on different interfaces

Tags: wireless, networking, ssh, samba, android

As the title suggests, I have tried everything but cannot see my Desktop 14.04 Ubuntu Gnome box from my laptop running the same distro, and vice versa. However, I CAN see my laptop samba shares from my Android phone using ES File Explorer.

Please do not suggest NFS or SSH or SFTP or SSHFS, as I have windows devices that occasionally connect, and I would rather get this thing up and running using Samba.

I should also mention that the router I use is a D Link DSL-2750 U and I can access the internet on both eth0 and wlan0. The problem arises when I try to ping the laptop locally (192.168.--) It fails when I do it from the desktop, and vice versa.

So basically my ethernet-connected desktop cannot see/ping my laptop, but my phone which is on the same wireless network as my desktop can.

I've tried everything I can including configuring the router, and going to factory settings. But I cannot for the life of me seem to fix this seemingly silly problem.

ANY help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried editing /etc/samba/smb.conf

Comment: I have, I've changed Samba settings on both ends a million times. I think the problem is with my hardware (router) or the software configuration that controls it. ES can access my laptop over WiFi, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command and check whether you are able to configure samba,

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

Comment: Hi! I did this. I'm beginning to think it's because my laptop is on WiFi and my desktop uses LAN. Because when I reset my Samba file on both laptop and PC, and connected both to the same router using LAN cables, they found each other.

Comment: Interestingly, my WiFi and LAN are on the same subnet, 192.168.0.50 onwards. The PC uses a MAC-reserved .50 address and the laptop has a .51 MAC-reserved address.

My router does not allow using a different subnet for WiFi and LAN so I guess there's no way of fixing this. (IF a subnet-related fix were possible)

Comment: Here is my nmap result when I try to find my LAN connected desktop from my WLAN connected laptop.

nmap 192.168.0.50 -Pn

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-12-30 10:04 IST
Nmap scan report for DFAIENCE (192.168.0.50)
Host is up (0.082s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on ******** (192.168.0.50) are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.05 seconds